# Error using Prelude.read in Hamlet Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I get an error when I use the following Haskell code inside Hamlet Yesod:

```
#{show $ (read "True" :: Bool)}
```

It seems it doesn't accept `':'` characters, but I actually need it.

The error is the following:

```
Handler/Game.hs:85:11:
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      "#{show $ read "True" :: Bool}" (line 1, column 25):
unexpected ":"
expecting "}"
```

Is it possible to bypass this error and be able to use `Prelude.read`?

Comment: Though I am not familiar with Yesod, that seems redundant. The expression within the braces is equivalent to `"True"`. Applying `read` and then `show` is in most cases a no-op.

Comment: Usually you don't need to call any functions inside a view, leave it to a controller or a model and store it in a variable. If you really want, you can use as-functions from `classy-prelude` of define it yourself, i.e. `asBool = id :: Bool -> Bool`.

Comment: @duplode I know it's redondant. I just used as an example for the error.